# Update and access /home/user/profile in ksh script

Tags: shell, ksh

In the sample script, I'm not able to access `$HW_NAME` without a re-login

I hope to access the export variables after sourcing the profile with a script and in the following scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93

alias=();
alias+=("alias hello='export HW_NAME="HelloWorld";'")
printf '%s\n' "${alias[@]}" >> ~/.profile

source ~/.profile

. ~/.profile

echo $HW_NAME
```

Comment: Don't run this like a program, you need to source it.